# Microsoft PowerAutomate

Tags: windows

I am currently building an out of office workflow in Microsoft powerautomate for Teams. When a request for 8/19/20 gets submitted it gets changed to 8/20/20 and same thing with the end date. Is there a way to set a it so it shows the actual dates selected?

Answer (score 1):

So i think this is happening due to Default UTC time zone is used by Power Automate. Here is a flow that uses the Convert time zone action with a base time of utcNow().  Convert the time to needed timezone and then used an Update item action to update a date field with that converted time value.  The correct time shows up in my SharePoint list
[image: Convert your date object according to timezone]
[image: use converted date time in update item action]
[image: Result]

Hope this may help you.